# How would I approach "reflecting" a rust structure's schema into JSON?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to "reflect" a structure in `rust`? I want to take a structure, and serialize it in a way that the types and field names appear in a JSON structure.  Ideally I'd want something like:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct AboutRsp {
    /// The name of the project that built this binary
    pub title: String,
    /// The name of the binary as built.
    pub name: String,
    /// The version number of the project.
    pub ver: String,
    /// Short description of this binary and it's purpose.
    pub desc: String,
    /// The hash from the repo that houses the source code of this project.
    pub git_hash: String,
    /// The list of authors contributing to this project.
    pub authors: String,
}
```

to become a JSON object that looks like:

```
"aboutrsp" : {
        "title": {"type": "String", "description": "The name of the project that built this binary" },
        "name": {"type": "String", "description": "The name of the binary as built." },
        "ver": {"type": "String", "description": "The version number of the project." },
        "desc": {"type": "String", "description": "Short description of this binary and it's purpose." },
        "git_hash": {"type": "String", "description" : "The hash from the repo that houses the source code of this project."},
        "authors": {"type": "String", "description" : "The list of authors contributing to this project."}
    }
```

The example I've shown is arbitrary and I'm looking for a general solution.  A perfect solution would show the field's type and pick up the description from the `rust` docstring *OR* would have a macro that defines both the structure (and the docstring) and a second structure populated appropriately.

Comment: I found this post that shows how to include type iformation using serde with a custom serializer: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1095

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search reveals [`schemars`](https://docs.rs/schemars/):

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, schemars::JsonSchema)]
pub struct AboutRsp {
    /// The name of the project that built this binary
    pub title: String,
    /// The name of the binary as built.
    pub name: String,
    /// The version number of the project.
    pub ver: String,
    /// Short description of this binary and it's purpose.
    pub desc: String,
    /// The hash from the repo that houses the source code of this project.
    pub git_hash: String,
    /// The list of authors contributing to this project.
    pub authors: String,
}

fn main() {
    let schema = schemars::schema_for!(AboutRsp);
    let schema_string = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&schema).unwrap();
    println!("{schema_string}");
}
```

Prints:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "AboutRsp",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "authors",
    "desc",
    "git_hash",
    "name",
    "title",
    "ver"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "authors": {
      "description": "The list of authors contributing to this project.",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "desc": {
      "description": "Short description of this binary and it's purpose.",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "git_hash": {
      "description": "The hash from the repo that houses the source code of this project.",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "description": "The name of the binary as built.",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "description": "The name of the project that built this binary",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ver": {
      "description": "The version number of the project.",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thought's on how I would only show the value of the "properties" field?

Comment: @Jamie `schema_for!()` returns a typed [`RootSchema`](https://docs.rs/schemars/latest/schemars/schema/struct.RootSchema.html). You can always pick whatever you want from it, and serialize it however you like.

Comment: @Jamie An easier (but less efficient and less flexible) path is to [serialize into `serde_json::Value` instead of a string](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/fn.to_value.html), and traverse it to pick the `properties` field.